# Node Create Server

Tags: node.js, server, request, response

I'm new to node Js - I tried to create server with node , this is my code 
[Node Create Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDFtK.png)

it is throwing following error , can anyone guide me to create Server or fix this issue ?
[Create Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoDfZ.png)

Comment: Per the guidelines here at stackoverflow, all code that is needed to understand the question MUST be pasted directly into the question and formatted appropriately.  External links are OK as an additional reference, but not as the primary means of understanding the question.  This is because external links tend to disappear or change over time which would then render the question useless as a long-term reference (which is one of stack overflow's goals).  So, please paste the relevant code to understand the question into your question itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is syntax error. You wrote on 4. line `funtion` it is not true. Write `function`